# Ruby way instead of for loop in specific case of array iteration

Tags: arrays, ruby, for-loop, each, curly-braces

Coming from other languages where for loop is predominant way of iterating, I am curious is there a better more Ruby style way to achieve below:

```
q=[5,1,7,9,0,3,6,8,0]

for i in 0..q.size/3-1

  do one thing with q[0+i*3]

  do another one with q[1+i*3]

  third operation on q[2+i*3]

end
```

THX!

Code submitted in question actually works, but knowing that for in Ruby uses each under the hood, I am not sure what is the best way to make it more compact&efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most Ruby way to do this would probably be to use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```ruby
q.each_slice(3) do |first, second, third|
  # do something with `first`
  # do another thing with `second`
  # third operation with `third`
end
```

For example:

```ruby
q.each_slice(3) do |first, second, third|
  p({ first:, second:, third: })
end
# { first: 5, second: 1, third: 7 }
# { first: 9, second: 0, third: 3 }
# { first: 6, second: 8, third: 0 }
```

In general, one of the most important operations in *any* program is "iterating over stuff" (or more generally, traversing, transforming, filtering, building, and folding collections), and in Ruby, that is handled by the [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerable.html) mixin. Studying and understanding this mixin's documentation is *crucial* to writing good, idiomatic Ruby code.

As a (slightly exaggerated) general rule, if you have to write a loop or manually fiddle with indices or counters in Ruby, you are very likely doing something wrong. In fact, with the powerful algorithms, data structures, and collections libraries that are shipped with most modern programming languages, that does not just apply to Ruby but almost universally.

Comment: ZoRaN, notice that `enum1 = q.each_slice(3) #=> #<Enumerator: [5, 1, 7, 9, 0, 3, 6, 8, 0]:each_slice(3)>`. We can see the objects this enumerator will generate by converting it to an array: `Enum1.to_a #=> [[5, 1, 7], [9, 0, 3], [6, 8, 0]]`. But wait, `each_slice` is an `Enumerable` method, but `q`, being an array, only responds to `Array` methods. So how does that work?...

Comment: ...For a class to be able to use methods defined in the module `Enumerable`, the class (`Array` being one) must satisfy two requirements: it must [Module#include](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-include) the module (e.g., `Array.include(Enumerable)`) and define a method `each` on the class that returns an enumerator (i.e., an instance of the class `Enumerator`). That's because `Enumerable` methods can only be invoked on objects that are elements of the class `Enumerator`...

Comment: ...So there is actually a step that you are not seeing: `enum0 = q.each #=> #<Enumerator: [5, 1, 7, 9, 0, 3, 6, 8, 0]:each>` (note: `enum0.to_a #=>
[5, 1, 7, 9, 0, 3, 6, 8, 0]`), then `enum1 = enum0.each_slice(3) #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [5, 1, 7, 9, 0, 3, 6, 8, 0]:each>:each_slice(3)>` . Many built-in classes include `Enumerable` and define `each` on the class, (`Hash` and `Range` being two others). You can include `Enumerable` methods in custom classes in the same way. Now, `enum1.map { |arr| arr.sum } #=> [13, 12, 14]`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, `each_slice` is pretty much the ideal answer here.

However if you were purely interested in looping over the *numeric indices*, transforming the code you have into something more idiomatically Ruby, you might use a range and `step` to move forwards by in increments of 3:

```
q=[5,1,7,9,0,3,6,8,0]

(0..q.size - 1).step(3) do |i|
  a = q[i]
  b = q[i + 1]
  c = q[i + 2]

  p [a, b, c]
end

# [5, 1, 7]
# [9, 0, 3]
# [6, 8, 0]
```